# What is the difference between $_FILES["file"]["type"] and end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]))

Tags: php, file

I use `var_dump(@$_FILES['file']['type'])` to test file type I uploaded

First, I uploaded an `exe file` called "`uninstall.exe`", and it returned

```
"string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)"
```

Then, I renamed this file to `uninstall.png`, it returned

```
string 'image/png' (length=9)
```

My conclusion is: **$_FILES['file']['type'] only check file extension, not the original file type.**

The following code is from [w3cschool](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

I think `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` in above codes is unnecessary, we can just check file extension using `explode()` and `in_array`

I'm just a php beginner, can someone confirm my idea? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I believe many of us know that the file type can be spoofed.

Comment: A lesson in not using w3schools

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy I found something wrong in w3cschool

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['type']` does not check extension - it is information send in request headers from user machine. It can be used as a hint (for non standard file formats, that is recognizable on user machine but not on server) but should not be trusted in terms of security.

Comment: @user1970939 finding something wrong on w3schools is not that hard... (also note that this is not `w3c`schools but `w3`schools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. The MIME type is provided by the client and you cannot guarantee it is cor­rect. For that matter, so is the file extension. If you need to be completely sure, you need to look at the file contents.

Comment: I'm glad my idea got confirmed, someone said:"the extension of the file and 'file type' can be differ, so someone can not upload executable file with .png extension with $_FILES["file"]["type"]." I think he is wrong

Comment: @user1970939: Well, someone actually could provide a file named `file.exe` with a MIME type of `image/png`. They're both provided by the client and are not required to be consistent.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be sure that an image was uploaded, use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/getimagesize), that returns 0 for non-images.

Comment: and some JPEGs even. Mostly JPEGs that come from digital cameras.

Comment: thanks for mentioning  getimagesize

Comment: @darthmaim absolutely incorrect! `getimagesize` can and will return successfully for some non-images. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: It says in the official PHP docs NOT to use `getimagesize`. "Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead."

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a wrapper of GD or Imagick extensions. A very good one is [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).