# Correct way to validate file upload in PHP - including user changing file extension?

Tags: php, image, file, validation, upload

Currently I check all elements of an image in PHP before I allow it to be uploaded. But when it comes to things like file extensions I'm a bit concerned.

I use the following to only allow files of a certain type to be uploaded:

```
$allowed_ext = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png");

$tmp_ext = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$ext = strtolower(end($tmp_ext));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($ext, $allowed_ext)) {
    //Continue
} else {
    //Don't allow
}
```

But does this prevent all forms of users changing file extensions themselves? e.g. If a user changed the file extension of something malicious to .jpeg or .png - would this prevent it?

I can't find any posts clarifying this, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no, you can't rely on the MIME type.  Both the type and the file extension are provided by the client.

Looks like you can use getimagesize() for verifying an image, credit to this thread: [PHP: $_FILES["file"]["type"] is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605030/php-filesfiletype-is-useless)

Comment: What will you be doing with the images?  Displaying them in the browser?

Comment: Any decent browser should protect against malicious code in images so I don't think you'll have to worry.  If you're truly concerned you can use a combination of getimagesize() and see about using a ClamAV extension/program to scan files for malicious code.  Nothing is perfect though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the file extension and match it to the file type, if they do not match: fail.
2. Using the file format specified by the extension/MIME type call the appropriate `imagecreatefrom*()` function from the GD library. If it is anything other than an image of the type specified by the extension/MIME type the function will return `false`.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php