# HttpClient POST upload fails with no file transfered and maleformed generated ContentDisposition

Tags: c#, api, http, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I try to mirror images on my own image hoster, which contains a simple API that accepts default form data uploads like this:

```
-----------------------------149841124823007
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ZMVdEwM.png"
Content-Type: image/png
<Binary image data...>
```

This upload was tested using a simple html form and works well. Now I want to use this API in an .NET Core Standard application. Found [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212406/how-to-send-a-file-and-form-data-with-httpclient-in-c-sharp) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload):

```
string url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwGdv.png";
var client = new HttpClient();
var imageData = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent($"-----------------------------{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
string fileName = new Uri(url).LocalPath.Replace("/", "");
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageData), "file", fileName);
var postResp = client.PostAsync("https://my-image-hoster/api.php", content).Result;
string resp = postResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(resp);
```

I'm downloading the test image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwGdv.png as byte array and try to build the same form-data upload. But it fails here on my api:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('errorcode' => 'no_image_transfered'));
}
```

While investigation the problem, I inspected the `MultipartFormDataContent` instance called  `content` since it's responsible for building the request body. It shows a `ContentDisposition` property containing the file name twice: The first one is correct, but the second one looks maleformed:

[image]

What's wrong with my POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that `MultipartFormDataContent.Headers.ContentType` is the value of the HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------149841124823007
```

This was taken from the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42212590/3276634), which breaks my API since it expects `multipart/form-data`. So it's better to dismiss the type, unless your API checks the provided file type in `$_FILES['file'][0]['type']` because this is empty. The type came from the body:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ZMVdEwM.png"
Content-Type: image/png <--- type
```

Since it's a value provided by the client, we [shouldn't trust this data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15605047/3276634) and fetch the mime-type on the server side. If you have an API that checks this value (and no influence on the API itself) just set it for the *body* like this:

```
content.ElementAt(0).Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
```

Otherwise if you're fine with a `multipart/form-data` upload that doesn't contain the mime type, do your upload like this:

```
string url = "https://i.imgur.com/0acC9nr.png";
var client = new HttpClient();
var imageData = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
string fileName = new Uri(url).LocalPath.Replace("/", "");
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageData), "file", fileName);
// Optionally when the Content-Type body field is required
// content.ElementAt(0).Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
var postResp = client.PostAsync("https://my-image-hoster/api.php", content).Result;
var resp = postResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```